# How to compile compass sass using gulpjs

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gulp

Having difficulty compiling my sass that includes a compass import using gulpjs, I've read a few articles that include the config.rb compass file but was wondering if this is completely necessary as with grunt I don't need to do this?

**Here is my compass gulp entry for this:**

```
gulp.task('compass', function () {
    gulp.src('./css/src')
        .pipe(compass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

**My usual grunt entry for this is:**

```
compass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    cssDir: 'css',
                    environment: 'production',
                    force: true,
                    outputStyle: 'compact',
                    sassDir: 'css/src',
                    specify: 'css/src/base.scss'
                }
            }
        }
```

If anyone can help explain what I need to do that would be great

Comment: Did you read gulp-compass's docs? https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-compass

Answer (score 3):

You need to set config options when you run the `compass()` command. ex:

```
compass({
  config_file: './config.rb',
  css: 'stylesheets'
})
```

Definitely read the gulp-compass docs: https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-compass